# I see my clients in AD but not in WSUS

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, group-policy, groups, windows-service

I set up a WSUS but dont see any clients in the Unassigned Computers group. I can find my clients in the ADAC, when I select myWSUS (local) > computers. 
My group policy management got a domain myWSUS.local but I dont see the groups here, is this maybe the problem?

those are some of the errors i got in the windowsupdate log:

```
2015-07-29  03:02:27:702     852    86c Agent   ***********  Agent: Initializing global settings cache  ***********
2015-07-29  03:02:27:702     852    86c Agent     * Endpoint Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2015-07-29  03:02:27:702     852    86c Agent     * WSUS server: <NULL>
2015-07-29  03:02:27:702     852    86c Agent     * WSUS status server: <NULL>
2015-07-29  03:02:27:702     852    86c Agent     * Target group: (Unassigned Computers)
2015-07-29  03:02:27:702     852    86c Agent     * Windows Update access disabled: No
2015-07-29  03:02:27:703     852    59c Misc    WARNING: Network Cost is assumed to be not supported as something failed with trying to get handles to wcmapi.dll
2015-07-29  03:02:27:710     852    59c WuTask  WuTaskManager delay initialize completed successfully..
2015-07-29  03:02:27:715     852    59c Report  CWERReporter::Init succeeded
2015-07-29  03:02:27:715     852    59c Agent   ***********  Agent: Initializing Windows Update Agent  ***********
2015-07-29  03:02:27:715     852    59c DnldMgr Download manager restoring 0 downloads
2015-07-29  03:02:27:718     852    59c AU  ###########  AU: Initializing Automatic Updates  ###########
2015-07-29  03:02:27:719     852    59c AU  AIR Mode is enabled
2015-07-29  03:02:27:721     852    59c AU    # AU is not configured yet
2015-07-29  03:02:27:721     852    59c AU    # Will interact with non-admins (Non-admins are elevated (User preference))
2015-07-29  03:02:27:721     852    59c AU    # Accelerated install is required
2015-07-29  03:02:27:721     852    59c Agent   Switching to hardware-verified ClientId.
2015-07-29  03:02:27:721     852    59c AU  WARNING: Failed to get Wu Exemption info from NLM, assuming not exempt, error = 0x80240037
2015-07-29  03:02:27:722     852    59c AU  AU finished delayed initialization
2015-07-29  03:02:27:723     852    59c AU  Triggering AU detection through DetectNow API
2015-07-29  03:02:27:724     852    59c AU  Can not perform non-interactive scan if AU is interactive-only
```

I would love to give more data if needed.

Thanks in advance for helping me out

EDIT:
still not working.
WindowsUpdate.log:

```
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  AU received policy change subscription event
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  AU Options changed from policy.
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  ###########  AU: Policy change processed  ###########
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU    # Policy changed, AU refresh required = Yes
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU    # Policy Driven Provider: http://CONETWSUS
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU    # Detection frequency: 22
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU    # Target group: test-wsus
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU    # Approval type: Pre-download notify (Policy)
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU    # Will interact with non-admins (Non-admins are elevated (Policy))
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  AU Refresh required....
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  AU setting next detection timeout to 2015-07-30 07:26:06
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  AIR Mode is disabled
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  #############
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  ## START ##  AU: Download updates
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  #########
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU    # Found no download approved updates.
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  #########
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Download updates
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  #############
2015-07-30  09:26:06:389     900    12e0    AU  Triggering Online detection (non-interactive)
2015-07-30  09:26:09:392     900    12e0    AU  #############
2015-07-30  09:26:09:392     900    12e0    AU  ## START ##  AU: Search for updates
2015-07-30  09:26:09:392     900    12e0    AU  #########
2015-07-30  09:26:09:392     900    12e0    Agent   Created new random SusClientId f03f3cca-d74b-48b3-836b-598ce7cab02b. Old Id: none.
2015-07-30  09:26:09:392     900    12e0    Report  ***********  Report: Initializing static reporting data  ***********
2015-07-30  09:26:09:392     900    12e0    Report    * OS Version = 6.2.9200.0.0.131344
2015-07-30  09:26:09:392     900    12e0    Report    * OS Product Type = 0x00000007
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Computer Brand = Microsoft Corporation
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Computer Model = Virtual Machine
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Platform Role = 1
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * AlwaysOn/AlwaysConnected (AOAC) = 0
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Bios Revision = 090006 
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Bios Name = BIOS Date: 05/23/12 17:15:53  Ver: 09.00.06
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Bios Release Date = 2012-05-23T00:00:00
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Bios Sku Number unavailable.
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Bios Vendor = American Megatrends Inc.
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Bios Family unavailable.
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Bios Major Release unavailable.
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Bios Minor Release unavailable.
2015-07-30  09:26:09:423     900    12e0    Report    * Locale ID = 1033
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    12e0    AU  <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates  [CallId = {B1D003F5-53F5-402D-9060-0579E48C3ED7} ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}]
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    10bc    Agent   *************
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    10bc    Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    10bc    Agent   *********
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    10bc    Agent     * Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    10bc    Agent     * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1"
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    10bc    Agent     * ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    10bc    Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine & All Users}
2015-07-30  09:26:09:533     900    10bc    Agent     * Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-18
2015-07-30  09:26:09:754     900    10bc    Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77\wuredir.cab:
2015-07-30  09:26:09:775     900    10bc    Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2015-07-30  09:26:09:775     900    10bc    Misc     Infrastructure signed: Yes
2015-07-30  09:26:09:775     900    10bc    EP  Got WSUS Client/Server URL: "http://CONETWSUS/ClientWebService/client.asmx"
2015-07-30  09:26:09:775     900    10bc    Setup   Checking for agent SelfUpdate
2015-07-30  09:26:09:775     900    10bc    Setup   Client version: Core: 7.8.9200.16384  Aux: 7.8.9200.16384
2015-07-30  09:26:09:775     900    10bc    EP  Got WSUS SelfUpdate URL: "http://CONETWSUS/selfupdate"
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80190194
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80190194
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Misc    WARNING: DownloadFileInternal failed for http://CONETWSUS/selfupdate/wuident.cab: error 0x80190194
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Setup   WARNING: SelfUpdate check failed to download package information, error = 0x80244019
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Setup   FATAL: SelfUpdate check failed, err = 0x80244019
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Agent     * WARNING: Skipping scan, self-update check returned 0x80244019
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Agent     * WARNING: Exit code = 0x80244019
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Agent   *********
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Agent   *************
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    10bc    Agent   WARNING: WU client failed Searching for update with error 0x80244019
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    528 AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {B1D003F5-53F5-402D-9060-0579E48C3ED7} ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}]
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    528 AU    # WARNING: Search callback failed, result = 0x80244019
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    528 AU  #########
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    528 AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates  [CallId = {B1D003F5-53F5-402D-9060-0579E48C3ED7} ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}]
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    528 AU  #############
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    528 AU  All AU searches complete.
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    528 AU    # WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 80244019
2015-07-30  09:26:10:010     900    528 AU  AU setting next detection timeout to 2015-07-30 12:26:10
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't configured the WSUS settings in Group Policy yet.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like that client isn't pointed to the WSUS server. Without it pointed there and told to report it won't show up in WSUS.

```
2015-07-29  03:02:27:702     852    86c Agent     * WSUS server: <NULL>
2015-07-29  03:02:27:702     852    86c Agent     * WSUS status server: <NULL>
```

See this Microsoft article for setting up a group policy for redirecting clients to your WSUS server:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc720539(v=WS.10).aspx

Make sure the "intranet statistics server" is also set.

Comment: hey thanks for helping me out, its still not working, i edited mt question

Comment: Looks like you have an issue with your WSUS server. WARNING: DownloadFileInternal failed for http://CONETWSUS/selfupdate/wuident.cab: error 0x80190194

Comment: If you put that url into a web browser, it should download a cab file if the WSUS server is setup correctly and that URL is correct. I would also use a fqdn instead of just a hostname.